# Two different AJAX requests on one PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got one register.php file, which has two basic `if` statements, like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['register_company'])){...}
```

and

```
if(isset($_POST['register_user'])){...}
```

When I was posting my submit forms to the register.php, it was no problem; the correct submit was proceeding to the correct `if` statement.

Now I'm using AJAX, and I need to differentiate somehow which AJAX request is going to which `if`.

So far I'm using basic `function is_ajax_request()`:

```
function is_ajax_request(){
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
}

if (is_ajax_request()) {...}
```

I know my question is trivial, but hope you know a lot better how to deal with it. So my question is: how to adress two different AJAX requests to two different `if` statements in one PHP file?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Kisaragi - how to adress two different ajax requests to two different if statements on php file?

Comment: Send an additional parameter that allows you to discern between the two ...?

Comment: @CBroe - sure, that seems easy